# How to get the ObjectId attribute in mongodb to show it in ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

How to get the attribute if it is an object id,
i want to do the `console.log(orders[0].cart.items.'5fcdad28db5c902e86eb2937')` to show what is inside the `5fcdad28db5c902e86eb2937` object but the problem is i dont know how to get the `5fcdad28db5c902e86eb2937` to insert it in the console.log. i want to put it in the ejs file to show the data.

```js
app.get('/orders', isLogin,async(req,res)=>{
  const db = await products.find({})
  const orders = await Orders.find({})
  const orders_list = await Orders.distinct('cart.items.5fcdad28db5c902e86eb2937.item.name')
  var a = req.user._json.name
  var b = req.user.photos[0].value
  var c = req.user._json.email


 
  console.log(orders[0].cart.items)
  

  res.render('orders.ejs',{
    orders,
    orders_list,
    userName:a,
    picture:b,
    email:c
  })
})
```

This is the db

```js
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5fd86f0babb9936f1b5e7ec0"
  },
  "cart": {
    "items": {
      "5fcdad28db5c902e86eb2937": {
        "item": {
          "image": "1607314728363.png",
          "_id": "5fcdad28db5c902e86eb2937",
          "category": "Cleaning Equipment",
          "name": "Scotch Bright",
          "price": {
            "$numberInt": "100"
          },
          "stocks": {
            "$numberInt": "100"
          },
          "description": "For cleaning",
          "date": "2020-12-07T04:18:48.396Z",
          "__v": {
            "$numberInt": "0"
          },
          "color": null,
          "size": null
        },
        "qty": {
          "$numberInt": "3"
        },
        "price": {
          "$numberInt": "300"
        }
      },
      "5fd08d4e0dbfd178a2719877": {
        "item": {
          "image": "1607503182402.png",
          "_id": "5fd08d4e0dbfd178a2719877",
          "category": "Janitorial Supplies",
          "name": "Broom",
          "price": {
            "$numberInt": "100"
          },
          "stocks": {
            "$numberInt": "10"
          },
          "description": "aawit walis",
          "date": "2020-12-09T08:39:42.444Z",
          "__v": {
            "$numberInt": "0"
          }
        },
        "qty": {
          "$numberInt": "1"
        },
        "price": {
          "$numberInt": "100"
        }
      }
    },
    "totalQty": {
      "$numberInt": "4"
    },
    "totalPrice": {
      "$numberInt": "400"
    }
  },
  "name": "fefrf",
  "email": "dsf@fsdr",
  "contact": {
    "$numberInt": "32423432"
  },
  "address": "dsf@fsdr",
  "receive": "Delivery",
  "__v": {
    "$numberInt": "0"
  }
}
```

strong text

Comment: Consider using the square bracket notation? `orders[0].cart.items['5fcdad28db5c902e86eb2937']`?

Comment: Yes it work, but there are 2 objectId in the `items`, how can i get all objects? i tried .length to check if it will read all the objectid but it shows undefined

Comment: What do you mean? If you want all the items leave out `['5fcdad28db5c902e86eb2937'`

Comment: no, i want to get the data inside the `5fcdad28db5c902e86eb2937` also the other one to show it in my ejs file

Comment: You’ll probably have to use `Object.entries(orders[0].cart.items)` as items is not an array.